# Alert function not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning Javascript and jQuery from a book. I'm stuck. I'm learning how to store form input into a variable and it doesn't seem to work.

I can make it work with javascript. This gives me an alert with the email:

```
    function readAdd(){
        var getAddress = document.getElementById("emailAdd").value;
        alert(getAddress);
    }
```

I manage to make the code work with the following using jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $("form").on("submit", function(){
            var getAddress = $("input#emailAdd").val();
            alert(getAddress);
        })
    }
    );
```

However, the .on("submit",function(){}) is not taught in this chapter of the book, which leads me to believe that I'm suppose to combine jQuery with Javascript.  So I wrote the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        function readAdd(){
            var getAddress = $("input#emailAdd").val();
            alert(getAddress);
        }
    }
    );
```

When I execute, I get no alert. I'm assuming this is not the way to write jQuery and Javascript together. It is most likely an error on my part, but I'm lacking the understanding to properly test if the variable stores the value of the form or not. Can anyone help?

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript... In any case, you haven't shown where you're calling `readAdd`.

Comment: It's not enough to **define** functions, you need to **execute** them.  Either directly or through appropriate event handlers.

Comment: Thanks guys! That was what I needed to realize.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you define a function called `readAdd` but it is not executed. In order to execute it you must add `readAdd()` to the code, or you could test it opening the cosole and typing `readAdd()`.
The first code works because it executes `function()` when an HTML `form` is called to submit its contents.

Comment: Thanks man! I 'return readAdd();' and it worked perfectly!  It was probably a stupid question but I really appreciate the help.